# IndentationError while using formset

Tags: python, django

I have these models:

```
class Tour(models.Model):
   Name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Count=models.SmallIntegerField() 
   PriceUnitCode=models.ForeignKey(PriceUnit)
   Price=models.CharField(max_length=12)
   Description=models.TextField()
   ActionDate=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,editable=False)
   ActionUserCode=models.ForeignKey(User,editable=False)
   StatusTypeCode=models.ForeignKey(StatusType)

class Images(models.Model):
   Image = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery")
   Tour=models.ForeignKey(Tour)
```

I wanna design a form to add a tour and a set of Images for that Tour at the same form.
this is my FormModel:

```
class TourForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Tour
```

I do this in views.py :

```
def myview(request,key):  
    GalleryFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Tour,Images)   
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        form = TourForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            tour=form.save()
            formset=GalleryFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=tour)
            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.save()
    else:
        form = TourForm()
        formset=GalleryFormSet()
    return render_to_response('airAgency/addtour.html', {'form': form,'formset':formset})
```

in my template :

```
<form method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data" dir="rtl">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

but it has this error:

```
unexpected indent (views.py, line 122)
```

line 122 is this :

```
if(form.is_valid()):
```

of course I changed this code alot,but every time it has error in line 122 while the code in line 122 is changing every time!!!
what's wrong with it?!!!
thanks in advance

Comment: oh,my godddd!!I'm confused.after correcting indentiations,I have indentiation error in this line in views.py :if form.is_valid(): and when I remove this line to try,this line has indentaion error:tour=form.save()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very likely, your indentation differs in line 122, most probably because you have invisible differences in leading whitespace.

**Example:** You have many lines in a block, all start with a tab, which is displayed by your editor as ... 8 spaces. One of the lines (line 122) contains a space and a tab as leading whitespace, which is displayed by your editor as ... 8 spaces. You do not see the difference, yet, the line start is different for Python, and that is the problem.

**Advice:** Remove all leading space from line 122, then autoindent it with your editor to get consistent results. Or remove all leading whitespace from line 122 and use the same start as the rest of the block.

To verify this is the case, open your file with ViM, and type `:set list` (all characters). Now TAB will be displayed as `^I`, while space will be displayed as a single space character.

Comment: Agreeing with this answer, but I feel the need to emphasize that line 121 should be checked to determine the expected indentation.

Comment: Possibly yes, after fixing the indentation issue your code may work -- or not. I'm no Django expert, I see this question more as a low-level Python problem.

Comment: I corrected my indentaions,now it has error in this line in views.py:  formset=GalleryFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=tour)

Answer (score 3):

maybe you put spaces instead of tabs in that line (or the oposite), it happends to me sometimes

Comment: I always use 3 spaces for each indentaion,and it always works for me! now I've corrected indentations the error is for this line in views.py: formset=GalleryFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=tour)

Answer (score 1):

in python line 122 is:

```
if form.is_valid():
```

Answer (score 1):

The most common source of errors such as this one is indentation change in the previous method, or generally *up a few lines from where the actual error is reported*. The **most most** common source of the problem is copy+pasting something from the nets, which is either tabbed/spaced or indented more/less than what you are doing.

Your editor should warn you about stuff like this. For example Komodo IDE provides arrows to indicate indentation level. So load it up into a fancy editor, and use it to spot the problem. There's a SO post about python IDEs.

Comment: Komodo was just the first thing that popped into my head that has this feature. You should check the python IDE question here on SO.